# SQL how to limit only parent in OneToOne (with sortking by name)

Tags: sql, sorting, limit, one-to-one

Is that possible?
I have OneToOne relation

```
id | parent_id |  name | 
-------------------------
 1 |   null    | John |  
 2 |    1      | Agnes |  
 3 |    1      | Lucy |  
 4 |   null    | Bart |  
 5 |    4      | Madlen |
```

I wanna limit only parent to 1 and get output:

```
id | parent_id |  name | 
-------------------------
 1 |   null    | John |  
 2 |    1      | Agnes |  
 3 |    1      | Lucy |
```

Additionaly sorting by name should be by parent name first and then by child name like

(DESC)

```
id | parent_id |  name | 
-------------------------
 1 |   null    | John |  
 3 |    1      | Lucy |
 2 |    1      | Agnes |  
 4 |   null    | Bart |
```

(ASC)

```
id | parent_id |  name | 
-------------------------
 4 |   null    | Bart |  
 1 |   null    | John |  
 2 |    1      | Agnes |  
 3 |    1      | Lucy |
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: oracle, postgresql, sql-server...?

Comment: Can you add your queries per output required?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1 in (id, parent_id)
order by (case when id = 1 then 1 else 2 end), id;
```